# How to make completion works at first time in PhpStorm 2016.2

Tags: autocomplete, phpstorm, autosuggest

I'm using PhpStorm 2016.2 and my code completion does not seem to work properly. When typing `$this->assertCo`

[image: Too short list]

it suggest only function names that are up to third level ancestors of my class. But when I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> it suggest correct items.

[image]

This is my class diagram:

[image]

and missing suggestions are in `PHPUnit_Framework_Assert` class.

**How can I make it work without using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> every time?**

PhpStorm and OpenJDK info:

```
PhpStorm 2016.2
Build #PS-162.1121.38, built on July 12, 2016
JRE: 1.8.0_76-release-b216 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Reason for current behaviour:** it was asked by users ([WI-9403](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-9403)) **to hide static methods** when completing methods using `this->`.

PHPUnit apparently has all `assertXXX` methods done as **static** although recommends accessing them via `$this->` (same way how it's done in JUnit -- the original tool where PHPUnit devs took inspiration from).

> How can I make it work without using Ctrl+Space every time?

Right at the moment -- no way.

But in **2016.2.1** it will work as before for PHPUnit methods/inside PHPUnit test files ([WI-32530](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32530) -- already implemented).

---

You may also consider voting for https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-32713 -- to have such behaviour completely optional (additional setting) even outside of PHPUnit tests.